# How write Django model query to get product list with product available in wishlist or not?

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
models.py 
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    size_id = models.ForeignKey(size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    tax_id = models.ForeignKey(Tax, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()

class wishlist(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                      error_messages = {'unique': 'This Product is already in exist',})
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'm trying to fetch all product like product.objects.all() with check particular product available on cart and wishlist or not

Comment: Where do you know the product is available? This does not seem to be included in (another) model?

Answer (score 0):

The setup of your models is wrong. 
One wishlist can be assigned to one single owner (user). Yes correct use of `ForeignKey`
**But** with the code above you assign one wishlist to only one single product. Since you are using `ForeignKey` (same relationship as to the user), your wishlist can not hold multiple Products.

Instead you would want to use a [Many to Many Relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships). Because one wishlist can hold multiple Product and one Product can be hold by multiple wishlists.

```py
class wishlist(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

# Prefetch related products in cart and wishlist for the user
cart_prefetch = Prefetch('cart_set', queryset=Cart.objects.filter(user=user), to_attr='user_cart')
wishlist_prefetch = Prefetch('wishlist_set', queryset=Wishlist.objects.filter(user=user), to_attr='user_wishlist')

products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(cart_prefetch, wishlist_prefetch).all()

# Iterate over products
for product in products:
    in_cart = any(cart for cart in getattr(product, 'user_cart', []))
    in_wishlist = any(wishlist for wishlist in getattr(product, 'user_wishlist', []))
    print(f"Product {product.name} is in cart: {in_cart}, is in wishlist: {in_wishlist}")
```

Comment: user not allowed add same product into wishlist.

Comment: Yes, that's how Many to Many relationships work. You could create a `Wish` model that holds a product Id and has an amount field. One wishlist can then hold multiple Wishes.

Comment: The modeling is better *without* a `ManyToManyField`, since then you simply track at what time what user added what item to the wishlist. Here you will end up creating a *second* junction table, only resulting in less efficient queries, and with less data available when something was added to the wishlist. I think the name of the model `wishlist` is misleading, it should be `favorite`, but using a second `ManyToManyField`, does not generate extra value at all.

Comment: Sure, you have a valid point, thanks for the improvement! Anyways without changing the setup of the `wishlist`s `ForeignKey` the wish**list** can not be a list. I think that is important for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [**`Exists`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) with:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists

Product.objects.annotate(
    in_wishlist=Exists(
        wishlist.objects.filter(
            product_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id_id=request.user.id
        )
    )
)
```

The `Product` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.in_wishlist` that is `True` if there is a `wishlist` object with `request.user.id` as `user_id_id`, and `product_id` for that product.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `user`, instead of <s>`user_id`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`wishlist`</s> to `WishList`.

Comment: With also mentioning the `ForeignKey`-issue within the `wishlist`-model this is the better answer to the question.